# .NET Core 5 to .NET Core 6 migration exception

Tags: c#, .net-core

When I change a project's target framework from .NET Core 5 to .NET Core 6, the following code throws an exception, and it cannot be compiled.

```
if (Database.IsMySql())
{
    modelBuilder.MutableEntities()
                .Where(entity => entity.GetProperties().Any(DatabaseHelper.HasGeneratedTimestamp))
                .ForEach(entity =>
                {
                    var properties = entity.GetProperties().Where(DatabaseHelper.HasGeneratedTimestamp);
                    var table = entity.GetTableName();
                    var key = (entity.FindPrimaryKey() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"primary key not defined on {table}"))
                                     .Properties
                                     .Select(property => property.Name)
                                     .Apply(columns => columns.Count() > 1 ? $"({columns.Join(", ")})" : columns.First());
                    properties.Where(DatabaseHelper.IsOnInsert).ForEach(property =>
                    {
                        // property.SetDefaultValue(DateTimeOffset.Now);
                    });
                    properties.Where(DatabaseHelper.IsOnUpdate).ForEach(property =>
                    {
                        // // property.SetDefaultValue(DateTimeOffset.Now);
                        // if (property.ValueGenerated == ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate)
                        //     property.SetDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
                    });
                });
        }
```

Where `Any(DatabaseHelper.HasGeneratedTimestamp)` throws the following error:

> Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Func<IMutableProperty, bool>

[image: The intellisense of Any()]

How can I fix this error? Do any packages need to be updated?

Comment: What is the method signature of `DatabaseHelper.HasGeneratedTimestamp`?

Comment: Have you create any extension method for `Any()` because it has nullable `Func<IMutableProperty, bool>` PARAM that is cause an issue

Comment: @GWimpassinger public static bool HasGeneratedTimestamp(this IProperty property)

Comment: @KiranJoshi find definition of ```public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source); ```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is struggling to decide on a specific method overload - presumably `Any` gained some overloads, which is making things ambiguous; maybe help it:

```
.Any(prop => DatabaseHelper.HasGeneratedTimestamp(prop))
```

Comment: can I check any overloads on ```Any```?

Comment: tried. this message appeared. ```CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IMutableProperty' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty'```

Comment: @want_to_be_calm well, that seems to at least make the underlying problem more apparent...

Comment: @want_to_be_calm: can you change the parameter type of `HasGeneratedTimestamp(this IProperty propery)` from `IProperty` to `IReadOnlyProperty`. There was a change in the definition of `IMutableProperty` between EF Core 5 and EF Core 6.

Answer (score 0):

The interface `IMutableProperty` has been changed between [EFCore 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.imutableproperty?view=efcore-5.0) and [EFCore 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.imutableproperty?view=efcore-6.0) from

```
public interface IMutableProperty: IMutablePropertyBase, IProperty
```

to

```
public interface IMutableProperty: IMutablePropertyBase, IReadOnlyProperty
```

Therefore the type `IMutableProperty` is not compatible to `IProperty` anymore. The simplest solution would be to change your helper method from

```
 public static bool HasGeneratedTimestamp(this IProperty property)
```

to

```
 public static bool HasGeneratedTimestamp(this IMutableProperty property)
```

or

```
 public static bool HasGeneratedTimestamp(this IReadOnlyProperty property)
```